# C# - What is the difference between String Clone() and Copy() method

Tags: c#, string

i was wondeiring that if Copy() and Clone() method do the same task whats diffrence between them and which one to use

as per what i have searched aboout is that clone() makes a new string and copy() just do copy an existing string and use it

if this is correct than which one is better

Comment: There really isn't a good reason to use either method, tbh.

Comment: `string` is `ICloneable`, by not actually cloning anything. It just returns itself. `string.Copy()` is pointless, sure it creates a new string, but you can only tell via `Object.ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: In c# strings are Immutable - that means by default you never pass refs around, but the raw data each time. To copy or clone a string just go var string1 = string2; using the copy and clone methods will just add confusion

Comment: Did you read the documentation? [Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.clone) will not do anything, while [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy) _might_ create a new instance with the same value, or sometimes not.

Comment: @TheLemon yes, string is immutable. But you still pass refs around, not copies of the string contents. "equals" is overridden to perform a value equality instead of the default ref-equality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Don't use either method:

- `Clone` *doesn't actually do anything*.
- `Copy` is *officially obsolete*.

### Etc:

I'll preface my answer by saying that because `String` values are immutable there aren't really many (or any?) good reasons for using either `String.Clone()` or `String.Copy`.

> as per what i have searched aboout is that `clone()` makes a new string and `copy()` just do copy an existing string and use it

Sorry but your understanding is incorrect.

As per the documentation (emphasis mine):

`String.Clone()` **does not** create a copy of the string, in fact it just returns a self-reference:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.clone?view=net-6.0
>
> The return value is not an independent copy of this instance; it is simply another view of the same data. Use the `Copy` or `CopyTo` method to create a separate String object with the same value as this instance.
>
> **Because the `Clone` method simply returns the existing string instance, there is little reason to call it directly**.

As for `String.Copy()`:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy?view=net-6.0
>
> The `Copy` method returns a `String` object that has the same value as the original string but represents a different object reference.
>
> [...]
>
> Starting with .NET Core 3.0, **this method is obsolete**. However, we do not recommend its use in any .NET implementation. In particular, because of changes in string interning in .NET Core 3.0, in some cases the Copy method will not create a new string but will simply return a reference to an existing interned string.

Additionally, because `String.Copy` *might* create a copy (depending on how interning works)_ it means it's a `O(n)` operation.